Consumer not able to consume messages from queue - ActiveMQ Artemis
I would like to consume messages using the JMS Listener, However the listener is not able to consume the messages.
This is my configuration for Artemis embedded broker.
@Component
@EnableJms
public class ArtemisConfig {
    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "myTopic";

    @Bean
    public static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        return new CachingConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public void activeMQServer() throws Exception {
        Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationImpl();
        configuration.setPersistenceEnabled(false);
        configuration.setSecurityEnabled(false);

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("host", "localhost");
        params.put("port", 61616);
        params.put("Schema", "tcp");
        TransportConfiguration transportConfiguration =
            new TransportConfiguration(
                NettyAcceptorFactory.class.getName(), params);

        configuration.setAcceptorConfigurations(
            Collections.singleton(transportConfiguration));

        ActiveMQServer server =
            ActiveMQServers.newActiveMQServer(configuration);

        CoreAddressConfiguration coreAddressConfiguration =
            new CoreAddressConfiguration();
        coreAddressConfiguration.setName(TOPIC_NAME)
            .addRoutingType(RoutingType.MULTICAST);
        configuration.addAddressConfiguration(coreAddressConfiguration);

        QueueConfiguration queueConfiguration =
            new QueueConfiguration(TOPIC_NAME);
        queueConfiguration.setAddress(TOPIC_NAME);
        queueConfiguration.setName(TOPIC_NAME);
        queueConfiguration.setRoutingType(RoutingType.MULTICAST);
        queueConfiguration.setDurable(true);
        configuration.addQueueConfiguration(queueConfiguration);

        server.start();
    }

    @Bean(name = "jmsTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
            new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        factory.setConcurrency("1-4");
        return factory;
    }
}

This is my listener which consumes message from the queue
@Component
public class ArtemisListener {

  @JmsListener(destination = "myTopic", containerFactory = "myFactory")
  public void listener(Message message){
    System.out.println("Message received");
  }
}

I am running a test, In the logs, I can see that the queue is created and the message is sent to the specified address and the consumer is also created but the message is not consumed.
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ArtemisConfig.class})
public class ArtemisIT {

  @Autowired
  JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

  @Test
  public void checkIfListenerWorks() throws InterruptedException {
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("myTopic", "Hello");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
  }
}

I don't see "Message Received" in my logs.
AMQ601065: User anonymous is creating a queue on target resource: ServerSessionImpl(jms-session=*N/A*) [with parameters: [QueueConfiguration [id=null, name=730d9da3-3d8c-4042-8ef8-c51788f646a5, address=myTopic, routingType=MULTICAST, filterString=null, durable=false, user=null, maxConsumers=-1, exclusive=null, groupRebalance=null, groupBuckets=null, groupFirstKey=null, lastValue=null, lastValueKey=null, nonDestructive=null, purgeOnNoConsumers=false, consumersBeforeDispatch=null, delayBeforeDispatch=null, consumerPriority=null, autoDelete=null, autoDeleteDelay=null, autoDeleteMessageCount=null, ringSize=null, configurationManaged=null, temporary=true, autoCreateAddress=null, internal=null, transient=null, autoCreated=false]]]

AMQ601265: User anonymous is creating a core consumer on target resource ServerSessionImpl(jms-session=*N/A*) [with parameters: [0, 730d9da3-3d8c-4042-8ef8-c51788f646a5, null, 0, false, true, null]]

AMQ601500: User anonymous is sending a core message on target resource: ServerSessionImpl(jms-session=*N/A*) [with parameters: [TransactionImpl [xid=null, txID=13, xid=null, state=ACTIVE, createTime=1721642690458(Mon Jul 22 10:04:50 UTC 2024), timeoutSeconds=300, nr operations = 0]@78c18d2c, CoreMessage[messageID=0,durable=true,userID=d57b5c8f-4811-11ef-b49b-8045dd328039,priority=4, timestamp=Mon Jul 22 10:04:50 UTC 2024,expiration=0, durable=true, address=myTopic,size=480,properties=TypedProperties[__AMQ_CID=d5352bca-4811-11ef-b49b-8045dd328039,_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE=1]]@1550453457, true, false, RoutingContextImpl(Address=null, routingType=null, PreviousAddress=null previousRoute:null, reusable=null, version=0)

Any changes required in my config? As I see the server shutdown logs as soon as message is sent.

Did my answer address your question? If so, please accept it to help other users who have this same question in the future. Thanks!

The listener ArtemisListener uses containerFactory myFactory which has PubSubDomain enabled while the sender ArtemisIT doesn't enable PubSubDomain, i.e.
  @Test
  public void checkIfListenerWorks() throws InterruptedException {
    jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("myTopic", "Hello");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
  }


This worked for me. Thanks

Your question indicates that you're consuming from a JMS queue, but in the code you're using a JMS topic. The semantics and configuration are quite different between a JMS queue and topic so that might be the source of your problems.
First, if you're using a JMS topic then there's no need to configure a Core queue. You simply need an address which supports multicast. This documentation explains more about how JMS concepts map to the Core API. In fact, by default the broker will automatically create all the addresses and queues you need automatically so technically you don't even need to configure the address. Furthermore, the Core JMS client won't use the core queue that you've manually configured. It will create its own non-durable subscription queue in order to adhere to the expected JMS semantics.
Second, since JMS topics adhere to publish/subscribe semantics you must create your JMS topic subscription before the message is sent to the topic. It's not clear in your description that you're actually doing that.
